# How to typeset argmin and argmax in Markdown?

Tags: latex, markdown, jupyter-notebook, typesetting, mathematical-typesetting

There are posts in TeX.SE that shows how argmin and argmax with limits can be typesetted using the `\DeclareMathOperator*` command. But how to do this in Markdown?

I am especially interested in doing this in Jupyter Notebook when I'm documenting in Markdown.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The way to do this is by using the `\underset` command.

Syntax:

```
\underset{<constraints>}{\operatorname{<argmax or argmin>}}
```

Example:

$\underset{c\in C}{\operatorname{argmax}}$

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is what you look for

```
$ \hat{\theta}^{MLE}=\underset{a}{\operatorname{\argmax}} P(D|\theta) = \frac{a_1}{a_1+a_0} $
```

The trick is done by [\underset](http://tex.wikidot.com/snippets:overset-and-underset), which put a character under an expression, as you see below.

[image: underset arg max]

Anyway, I see widely used the simple underscore expression, along with `\arg`and `\max`, as you see below.

[image: plain arg max]

If you want to know something more about the many ways you can choose, take a look at here: *[Command for argmin or argmax?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/command-for-argmin-or-argmax)*

Hope to be helpful

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me when using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) for markdown-to-PDF conversion. (The subscript 'a' is correctly placed underneath the 'argmin'):

```
---
header-includes:
    - \newcommand{\argmin}{\mathop{\mathrm{argmin}}\limits}
---

Some text.

$A = \argmin_a f(a)$
```