# Layout of a formula in a bookdown file

Tags: r, formula, bookdown

In my *.Rmd file I'm writing something like this

```
$\text{Dia}_i = \max_{x, y \in C_i} d(x,y)$
```

And I was expecting this

[image: namelimits]

but when doing `bookdown::render_book(...)` and controlling the results in my browser firefox I got

[image: nonamelimits]

I found that this has something to do with the *namelimits* (first picture) and *nonamelimits* (second picture) but unfortunately I have no clue how to change the outcome.

**Question**: What kind of code chunk I have to add that I can switch between the two notations?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Edit_1**

[image]

Can I mix these two types?! The goal is to have an inline formula with the desired apperance.

**Edit_2**

This is my Code - the three dots (...) are the magic/unknown code

[image]

And this is my desired output

[image]

But sadly I get this

[image]

My wish summerized

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, following https://stackoverflow.com/a/61979164/13249862:

Add this to your YAML header:

```
header-includes:
    - \newcommand{\argmax}{\mathop{\mathrm{max}}\limits}
```

Then, you can write both equations:

```
This $\text{Dia}_i = \argmax_{x, y \in C_i} d(x,y)$, or this $\text{Dia}_i = \max_{x, y \in C_i} d(x,y)$.
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use `$\text{Dia}_i = \max_{x, y \in C_i} d(x,y)$` to get the desired result?

Comment: You need to insert two ```$$``` in each side of your equation.

Comment: It's fine. I'm changing my answer to account for both equations. This is what you're looking for, if I got it right.

Comment: I see your point. Maybe it's a bug, try filling an issue here: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues

Comment: Second edit is available... Hopefully it's not a bug...

Comment: Do not know if it's a bug or not, but I think I got the good answer now.

Comment: Your proposal doesn't work. I don't know why... But the accepted answer in your link worked for me. `In my text I want to have $\underset{x, y \in C_i}{\operatorname{max}} d(x,y)$ And now the text goes on in the same line...`